# How can I run nohup command in ansible playbook task?

Tags: ansible, nohup

I am pretty much beginner with ansible. I am trying to migrate linux scripts to perform a remote server startup using the nohup command and it does not work properly. The ansible results state change: true, but when I check if the process is up, it doesn't. Thus, I have to restart it manually.

Thanks for your help.

---

Here what I am doing:

```
- name: "Performing remote startup on server {{ SERVER }}"
  command: nohup {{ JAVA_HOME }}/bin/java {{ DYNATRACE_AGENT_REUS }} -jar -Dengine={{ ENGINE_NAME }} name-{{ ENGINE_JAR_VERSION }}.jar --server.port={{ ENGINE_PORT }} >{{ CONSOLE_LOG }} 2>&1 &
  args:
    chdir: "{{ SOMEVAR_HOME }}"
    async: 75
    poll: 0
    register: out
  - debug: 
      msg: '{{ out }}'
```

Results:

```
TASK [Performing remote startup on server] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [servername]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [servername] => {
    "msg": {
        "ansible_job_id": "160551828781.28405",
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "finished": 0,
        "results_file": "/home/admindirectory/.ansible_async/160551828781.28405",
        "started": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . kindly improve the question format

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `shell` instead of `command` module. Bash redirects do not work with `command`.

P.S. You are using ansible in a strange way. Create a systemd unit (system or user-level) and use `systemd` module to enable/start it.

Comment: Some custom linux doesn't have systemd, upstart etc! `nohup` is the only way in such case.